# How to scope methods in AnjularJS

Tags: angularjs, function, controller

I have this controller that has several functions that call each other. On success, I want to return something to be displayed (located in the last function). For some reason, without errors, the return is not working but the console.log is. Can someone please tell me why the return does not work and give me a solution please. Thanks so much!

```
.controller("dayController", function(){

  .controller("weatherController", function(){

    this.currentWeatherToDisplay = function(){
      if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotLocation,initialize);
      }
      else{
        alert("Device does not support geolocation");
        initialize();
      }

    };


    var currentLocation;

    //get the location coords
    function gotLocation(pos){
      var crd = pos.coords;
      currentLocation = loadWeather(crd.latitude+','+crd.longitude);
      initialize();
    }

    function initialize(){
      if(!currentLocation){
        loadWeather("Washington, DC");
      }

      else{
        loadWeather(currentLocation);
      }
    }


    function loadWeather(location){
      $.simpleWeather({
        location: location,
        woeid: '',
        unit: 'f',
        success: function(weather) {
          var html = weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp;
          console.log(html);
          return html;

        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          return error;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, mmmm you are use some jQuery plugin to get the weather given a current location, and like almost every jQuery plugins this use callbacks call to works (success, and error) first one i recommend you to rewrite this method to something like this:

```
function loadWeather(location){
  var defered = $q.defer();
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      var html = weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp;
      console.log(html);
      defered.resolve(html);

    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      defered.reject(error);
    }
  });
  return defered.promise;
}
```

Also you must inject the $q dependency to the controller, like this:

```
module.controller("weatherController", function($q){...}
```

or this

```
module.controller("weatherController", ['$q',function($q){...}
```

I recommend the last by minyfication improvement in angular, when you return a promise like the function *loadWeather*, you must understand some basic principles about the the $q (based kriskoval Q library), a promise is a expected value in the future, an have a method **then** to work with that data (its a very short concept), that means:

```
 function gotLocation(pos){
  var crd = pos.coords;
  loadWeather(crd.latitude+','+crd.longitude)
    .then(function(html){
      //html contain the expected html from loadWeather defered.resolve(html)
      currentLocation = html;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      //error contain the expected error by execute defered.reject(error)
      // maybe gonna try to initialize here
      initialize();
    })

 }
```

This must work, remember to change the initialize function to some like this:

```
 function initialize(){
   var promise;
  if(!currentLocation){
    promise = loadWeather("Washington, DC");
  }

  else{
    promise = loadWeather(currentLocation);
  }
  promise.then(function(html){
    // some logic with succesful call
  }, function(error) {
    // some logic with error call
  })
}
```

Comment: no luck! I don't understand why it doesn't return a global scope!